# Como aplicar um filtro no XML para importar os registros, usando PHP?

Tags: php, xml

Tenho um XML com diversos registros para fazer uma importação com o PHP. A parte de importar está ok, mas queria fazer um filtro antes de importar, por exemplo, importar apenas o registro que tem o ID 444, como posso fazer isso?

Pensei em baixar o xml editar e salvar como um novo XML, seria isso?

Exemplo XML:

```
<Imoveis>
 <Imovel>
  <Id>123</Id>
 </Imovel>
 <Imovel>
  <Id>444</Id>
 </Imovel>
</Imoveis>
```

Estou usando o `$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($return)` para baixar o xml, onde `$return` é o valor do XML retornado de uma API.

Comment: Não é só fazer uma comparação já visto que precisa criar um loop sobre os nodes? Como você está fazendo, é legal colocar o código atual.

Comment: então, é essa comparação que não sei como fazer. O script que faz a importação é um que já uso pronto, vou ver se consigo aqui pegar apenas a parte que faz a importação